# Does Google Talk push messages?

Tags: google-talk, push-notifications

I would like to know if Google Talk works like Gmail where it actually pushes your messages onto your phone instead of the phone pulling periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: Cool, so battery drain (by Gtalk) should essentially be null when no messages are received?

Comment: @Weboide I'm not completely familiar with the Jabber protocol but I would assume so, yes.

Comment: I suspect there is a minimal overhead, the server needs to know whether you are online. There might be regular pings. It's difficult to tell without digging into the code.

Comment: @DrG I think you're right about GTalk doing something like that, but I know some other clients don't do it.  If you lose your connection while using eBuddy, for example, you might remain "online" for days without knowing it.  (Which indicates to me that it only sends "I'm signing out now" messages rather than "I'm still online" messages.)

Answer (score 0):

No, GTalk messages are not received on Android GTalk client while away (sleeping). So I assume there is no pushing, as it is done in the Blackberry GTalk client.